# Книги и учебные ресурсы по криптографии

Tags: криптография, книги

Что посоветуете для изучения криптографии и смежных с ней областей?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

общефилософская книга о безопасности, помогает понять, почему безопасность не ограничивается криптографией: Брюс Шнайер *Секреты и ложь. Безопасность данных в цифровом мире*

Энциклопедического масштаба книги:

- Брюс Шнайер *Прикладная криптография: протоколы, алгоритмы и исходный код на C.*
- Венбо Мао *Современная криптография*

И мега энциклопедия, свод современных знаний о безопаности - *международный стандарт Common Criteria*. Очень толстый, очень запутанный, очень содержательный.

**ВДОГОНКУ**

Про Прикладную криптографию Шнайера. Я эту книжку "ботал", когда DES и MD5 ещё были разрешёнными алгоритмами. Поэтому я ручками по схемам в книжке писал реализации и сравнивал с приведёнными в конце книги. Затем я пытался шифровать файлы и сравнивал результаты с выводами Openssl. Долго разбирался, почему результаты не сходятся :)) Задно выучил, что такое ECB и CBC. Их тоже программировал. Делал свою реализацию RSA со своими большими числами. Медленно, неэффективно, зато руками понял, что почём. По-моему, AES в новом издании отсутствует. Его я осваивал по другим книгам. На пару с GCM.

Важность протоколов я осознал существенно позже, их учил уже по другим источникам. Поэтому не могу сказать, как там у Шнайера с протоколами. Но в любом случае следует освоить Diffie-Hellman и DSA. Пусть они и устарели, но идею открытых ключей дают прочувствовать только так.

Не уверен, что у Шнайера есть эллиптические кривые. ИМХО, про них я читал у Мао. Это нужно обязательно освоить, сейчас эллиптические кривые - основа практической криптографии.

Comment: Не совсем понял зачем нужно последнее предложение.

Comment: вот как раз Прикладную Шнайера начал читать. как посоветуете практиковаться?

Comment: @doctor_mabuze добавил про Шнайера